# Why does "Design Patterns" say 'two objects of the same type only need to share part of their interfaces'?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

On page 13 in the GoF book there is a statement:

```
Two objects of the same type need only share parts of their interfaces.
```

I am not sure I understand this sentence.

**EDIT**: full quote might indeed help to understand that

> A type is a name used to denote a particular interface. We speak of an
>   object as having the type "Window" if it accepts all requests for the
>   operations defined in the interface named "Window." An object may have
>   many types, and widely different objects can share a type. Part of an
>   object's interface may be characterized by one type, and other parts
>   by other types. *Two objects of the same type need only share parts of
>   their interfaces*. Interfaces can contain other interfaces as subsets.

Comment: "Interfaces" as we know them now weren't in widespread use back then. Possibly GoF just meant that 2 objects of the same class should restrain themselves to the exposed class methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In their language, an objects *interface* is the the entire public contract of the object (Don't think language implementation here).

> The set of all signatures defined by an object is called the **interface**
>   to the object.

A *type* is more like what you would think of as a declared interface....

> A **type** is a name used to denote a particular interface.

Imagine:

```
public class Foo : IBar, IBaz {}

public class Fuz : IBar, IBuz {}
```

A Foo and a Fuz are both IBar "types" but they only share that aspect of their respective interfaces.

Comment: yeah, thats probably exactly whats meant there, your answer is very clear

Answer (score 1):

a more full quote is:

> A type is a name used to denote a particular interface. We speak of an
>   object  as having the type "Window" if it accepts all requests for the
>   operations defined  in the interface named "Window." An object may
>   have many types, and widely different  objects can share a type. Part
>   of an object's interface may be characterized by  one type, and other
>   parts by other types. Two objects of the same type need only  share
>   parts of their interfaces. Interfaces can contain other interfaces as
>   subsets.

and pretty clearly, i think, this is talking about multiple inheritance.  for example you might have `TextWindow` and `MenuWindow` that both subclass `Window` along with other classes.   both objects can be considered, in the sense they are using, to have "type" `Window`, and they will both implement the operations associated with that type - they will both have `Window`'s methods.  but `TextWindow` may also subclass `TextEditor` while `MenuWindow` does not, so their **total set of methods** (what they mean by "interface") are not the same, even though the `Window` part overlaps.

http://www.uml.org.cn/c++/pdf/DesignPatterns.pdf

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what it means as I don't have the book. But an interface is the method signatures of the class, combined with the public variables. As a subtype of a particular type, is also a type of its parent class, it can have methods that it parent does not have, hence it only shares some of the interface of the parent. I have no idea if that is actually what it was talking about though.